# single tap for more events

Tags: android, android-studio, multi-touch

I'm building a piano, and I have the following problem.
When a button is pressed and holds pressed, it is not possible to press the next while still holding the current.
I need to play more than one note without removing the finger from the screen.
How could I solve this?

Comment: Have you had a look at the [Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/multi.html) website?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to look into adding an [OnTouchListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) to your Piano view. This will get events constantly as long as the user's finger is on the screen.

There's a helpful overview in the official [UI Events](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html) docs.

Comment: i need an exemple how to apply